# Мне нужно найти такие натуральные числа n, при котором выполняется равенство a^7 + a^3 = a^n + 1

Tags: математика, олимпиада

Число a - корень уравнения x^13 + x^10 + x^7 = 1.
Нужно найти такие натуральные числа n, при котором выполняется равенство a^7 + a^3 = a^n + 1
Я не знаю как мне даже подступится к решению, единстве я преобразовал выражение: a^3(a^4 + 1) = a^n + 1

Comment: это задача связана с программированием?. если нет, то вам лучше задать вопрос на http://math.hashcode.ru/ .

Comment: см. условия использования метки `математика`: https://i.imgur.com/caXjQ3X.png

Comment: А тут можно подробнее прочитать о том,  [на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Вам же уже ответили — https://qna.habr.com/q/1212564

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ответ дан на другом сайте.